# How to display a RadioButton list in PreferenceScreen (not in a Dialog)

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-settings

How can a list of radio buttons be shown within a `PreferenceSecreen` rather than in a dialog? It's really annoying having to click more than once just to select an item from this list.

**Expected result**

[image]

**Current result**

[image]

[image]

**app_preferences.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ListPreference
            android:key="prefPhotoFilter"
            android:title="Photo filter"
            android:entries="@array/photoFilters" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

**strings.xml**

```
<string-array name="photoFilters">
    <item name="1">Natural</item>
    <item name="2">Boosted</item>
    <item name="3">Saturated</item>
</string-array>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/Gnzlt/70bb82e91a90d240e8d78e5a8ff49c3b), you can extend [CheckBoxPreference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/CheckBoxPreference) and create a layout with a radio button.

Like this:
 First, create a new layout containing an only radio button let's call it

`preference_widget_radiobutton.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RadioButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false" />
```

then create a subclass of CheckBoxPreference:

```
class RadioButtonPreference : CheckBoxPreference {

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyle: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyle) { setView() }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null) : super(context, attrs) { setView() }


    private fun setView(){
        widgetLayoutResource = R.layout.preference_widget_radiobutton
    }

    override fun onClick() {
        if (this.isChecked) 
            return

        super.onClick()
    }
}
```

in your `app_preferences.xml` screen:

```xml
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Photo Filters">
        <Your_class_package_dirctory.RadioButtonPreference
                android:key="naturals"
                android:title="Natural" />
        <Your_class_package_dirctory.RadioButtonPreference
                android:key="boosted"
                android:title="Boosted" />
        <Your_class_package_dirctory.RadioButtonPreference
                android:key="saturated"
                android:title="Saturated" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
```

Now as you can see this will behave like normal CheckBox, it won't get uncheck the previous radio button, to solve this issue:

In your preference screen code:

```
class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat(), Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener{
    private val sharedPreference = AppPreferences()


    private var oldCheckedPreference: RadioButtonPreference? = null

    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.app_preferences, rootKey)

        findPreference<RadioButtonPreference>("naturals")?.apply {
            /*
            You can set the defualt button to be checked by:
              updateCheckedRadioButton(this)
            */
            onPreferenceClickListener = this@SettingsFragment
        }
        findPreference<RadioButtonPreference>("boosted")?.onPreferenceClickListener = this
        findPreference<RadioButtonPreference>("saturated")?.onPreferenceClickListener = this

    }

    private fun updateCheckedRadioButton(radioButtonPreference: RadioButtonPreference) {

        //Uncheck the previous selected button if there is.
        oldCheckedPreference?.isChecked = false
        radioButtonPreference.isChecked = true
        oldCheckedPreference = radioButtonPreference

    }

    override fun onPreferenceClick(preference: Preference): Boolean {
        if (preference is RadioButtonPreference)
            updateCheckedRadioButton(preference)

        return true
    }

}
```

and the result is:

[image: result]

Comment: Sorry, I thought you are writing your code in Java, I will update the answer.

Comment: Needs to be single choice, selection doesn't change when I choose different options. See latest screenshot.

Comment: What about when I select a secific `RadioButton`? E.g. if I click the 'boosted' `RadioButton` I want the background colour to change to `Color.GREEN`, and `Color.PINK` for the 'satureted' `RadioButton`.

Comment: Not the button, the background of the fragment.

Comment: do you mean the preference fragment screen?

Comment: Yes, so basically a different event to happen when each RadioButton is selected.

Comment: How can the theme be changed when the code is in a `Fragment`? Previously I used an `Activity` to do this.

Comment: See this link:
[link](https://medium.com/@JakobUlbrich/building-an-android-settings-screen-part-4-9558029827b7),
the first two XML code.

Comment: I meant programmatically so instead of using `listView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK)` I want to use something like `setTheme(R.style.MyDarkTheme)`

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea how to that in `PreferenceFragemte`, because usually, you want your settings screen to look the same as the activity, but there is a workaround:

first, create another theme for your activity that has a different style, then inside PreferenceFragment call that following `activity?.setTheme(R.style.YOUR_NEW_STYLE_NAME)
activity?.recreate()`
note calling that `activity.recreate()` this will recall onCreate() in your activity which might be costly, so you have to use something ViewModel to store your data.

Comment: Can you adjust your code so that it works from the activity?

Comment: Hmmm, this will add unnecessary code to the answer which doesn't fit the question, because It'll be related to `Preferencefragment`, not to `RadioButton` in the preferences screen.

Comment: Ok. Fair enough. I will ask a new question.